# Converting an Activity into a Fragment errors

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to convert an `Activity` into a `Fragment`, I fixed everything now I am left with an error on `getIntent`, can you please show me how it is done?

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    loginLoadingView = (LoadingView)getView().findViewById(R.id.loginLoadingView);
    if (().getIntent().hasExtra("userID")) {
        userID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("userID");
    }
```

and an error on `UserPostsFragment.this`

```
@Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    loginLoadingView.setLoading(false);
                    M.T(UserPosts.this, getString(R.string.ServerError));
                }
            });
```

Comment: `I need to convert an Activity into a Fragment` are you sure you really need it?

Comment: at least 2 choices : pass the intent from the activity as argument to the fragment ... or get the activity which contains this fragment and then get the intent from it ...

Comment: i need to combine two activities

Comment: can you show how to?

Comment: It should work if you do getActivity().getIntent()